# React installed react router but cannot get the page to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've installed react router and I'm trying to get the main page to render.

This is the current *index.js*

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';

import Layout from './components/Layout';
import NewsComponent from './components/NewsComponent';

<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Layout} />
    <Route path="/news" component={NewsComponent} />
  </div>
</Router>

const app = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout} />
  </Router>, app);
```

The Layout component contains the layout of the page.

What I'm I missing?

I'm I doing this wrong?

Comment: You might be missing `hashHistory` from `import` statement and that is causing your page not to load correctly. I dont know if you have omitted that just for this example or you are missing it really (same to ReactDOM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some references you are missing, I dont know if you have omitted them just for this example or you are really missing them. Try this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; //Missing in your example
import { 
  Router, 
  Route, 
  browserHistory //Missing in your example
  } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './components/Layout';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Then in your component you can even navigate through history:

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'

//Dont forget to bind this in the constructor
yourMethod (someParams) {
    hashHistory.push(someUrl)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with hashHistory - TypeError: _this.props.history is undefined

Comment: Try replacing `hashHistory` with `browserHistory`. Did you try the code I proposed or you are receiving that error with your code? And also, If you dont mind share your `Layout` component please... I suspect there is something wrong there, It sounds to me your are not binding some method where you are using `this.props.history`

Comment: @JakeBrown777 did you have the chance to take a look at what i said? Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly importing ReactDOM (import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'); it isn't automatically included when you import React.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to modifying your code [missing imports, etc.], you'd want to specifically mention the version of the react-router you are using. Assuming that you are using NPM

Try:

npm remove react-router

Then:

npm install --save react-router@3.0.0

React-router V4, which is installed by default, is a complete re-envisioning of the react-router and is not compatible with the codes written for the previous versions of react-router.

---

If you haven't used React in a while, I suggest you use create-react-app. Starting from there will be quite straightforward:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app